# Will the was6 plugin for maven work with WAS 7

Tags: java, maven-2, websphere-7

From what I can find there is no specific maven plugin for WAS 7, so I am wondering if the was6-maven-plugin will work with the newer version of the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked IBM the same very questions: officially yes, in reality the Jar Hell will give you some problems.. If I were you I would dimension a couple of days for issue resolution.

Answer (score 0):

was6-maven-plugin works for me on WAS7 without problems but you have to hack when you want to deploy multiple EARs from one Maven module.

You don't have an option to deploy multiple EARs as in Geronimo plugin where you could specify multiple artifactIds.

was6-maven-plugin has earFile that defaults to `${project.artifact.file}`