# Deploy a web-application on Websphere 8.5 using maven 3

Tags: websphere, maven-3

I´m trying to make a Maven Project from an existing web application using JSF. The Project
should be deployed on Web Sphere 8.5.

Since i'm new to Web Sphere, don´t know how to build the "ear" Module, in order to be deployable on Web Sphere 8.5.

Does anyone know, where i can find further Information about deploying a web application on Web Sphere 8.5 using Maven 3.0.3?

Thanking you in anticipation,
Mosen

Comment: You can get websphere from IBM and make .ear in IBM RAD based on Eclipse. You can get Maven from the Apache site.

Comment: Make sure you have context root set like mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/a/8510172/7634099

Answer (score 4):

I've never worked with WebSphere Application Server 8.5; but in the days I was playing with IBM WAS 6.1 the [WAS6 Maven plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/was6-maven-plugin/) worked pretty well (it seems [it works with WAS7 too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918407/will-the-was6-plugin-for-maven-work-with-was-7)). Here's a POM fragment from the plugin site that allows automatic EAR deployment:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>was6-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.2</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>integration-test</id>
      <phase>integration-test</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>installApp</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
    <wasHome>${was61home}</wasHome>
    <host>deploymentmanager.your.domain</host>
    <username>admin</username>
    <password>adminpassword</password>
    <targetCluster>nameOfCluster</targetCluster>
    <profileName>Dmgr01</profileName>
    <conntype>SOAP</conntype>
    <port>8879</port>
    <verbose>true</verbose>
    <updateExisting>false</updateExisting>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

That plugin is for deployment and other administrative task, for EAR generation you can use the [Maven EAR Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/) as described in 20InchMovement answer.

Comment: I'd just like to point out that `${was61home}` does not work for me with WebSphere 7, I had to define a custom property, `was7Home`, and assign it the correct path to the installation root to get this plugin to work for me.

Answer (score 4):

Hope this could helps:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.orctom.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>was-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.8</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>deploy</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <wasHome>${env.WAS_HOME}</wasHome>
                <applicationName>${project.build.finalName}</applicationName>
                <host>${local or remote address}</host>
                <server>server01</server>
                <node>node01</node>
                <virtualHost>default_host</virtualHost>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

From https://github.com/orctom/was-maven-plugin

Answer (score 3):

in order to package an *.ear, you don't need Websphere.
This can be accomplished with maven itself.

```
pom.xml:
<project>
...
<artifactId>YourApp</
<packaging>ear</packaging>
...
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <modules>
                        <jarModule>
                            <groupId>${project.parent.groupId}</groupId>
                            <artifactId>configurationApp</artifactId>
                        </jarModule>
                        <ejbModule>
                            <groupId>${project.parent.groupId}</groupId>
                            <artifactId>AnEjbModule</artifactId>
                        </ejbModule>
                    </modules>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
...
</project>
```

Then you add your dependencies.
On command line go to your project and run mvn package.
Because of the package defined in you pom.xml, the ear will be created and can be found in the YourApp/target directory.

On the websphere admin console you can simply install the ear.
After login, goto:

```
Applications->Websphere enterprise applications and install a new application.
```

Select your YourApp.ear and go for easiness through the fast path to install the app.
The port to check is probably

```
yourServerName:9080/YourApp.
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

See http://code.google.com/p/websphere-maven-plugin/

Websphere Maven Plugin provides goals to:

deploy ear on websphere 7
start application
stop application
uninstall
require websphere application client.